# Debugging Visual Studio .props files

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

While trying to debug Visual Studio 2019 configuration problems, I often find myself in a situation where I need to display debug strings in the `build output` window:

Sometimes I can display a debug string in the `build output` window by inserting a "one-liner" into a `.props` file, like this:

```
...
  <Target Name="ValidateDriverProperties" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <Message  Importance="high" Text="MyDebugMessage: '$(WDKContentRoot)'" />
...
```

The code fragment above is from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Common.targets` with WDK v10.0.19041.0 installed.

However, when I try to insert my "one-liner" debug message into another `.props` file, I get an error like this:
 `error MSB4066: The attribute "Importance" in element <Message> is unrecognized.`

```
...
  <MatchingWdkPresent Condition="Exists('$(WDKContentRoot)\Include\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\km\ntddk.h')">true</MatchingWdkPresent>
  <Message  Importance="high" Text="MyDebugMessage: '$(WDKContentRoot)'" />
...
```

The code fragment above is from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Default.props` with WDK v10.0.19041.0 installed.

**Question**:  How to reliably display a debug string in the VS `build output` window from an arbitrary `.props` file ?

*My question is not about the particular problem outlined below, but it might serve as a context:*
The `$(WDKContentRoot)` variable has a trailing backslash and the code: `$(WDKContentRoot)\Include\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\km\ntddk.h` generates a bad path with double backslash like this:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Include\x64\km\ntddk.h`

Comment: I don't think you need anything other than MSBuild bin log, https://msbuildlog.com/ Everything is there.

Comment: No, msbuildlog does not allow me to inspect variables in particular places of the code.